# Cytoscape: Help creating IF statement with function builder

Tags: macos, function, cytoscape

I would like to create a function to populate and edge table column with values that utilizes the built in function builder in Cytoscape. The problem is that only 4 functions are in the list. Every tutorial shows tons of available functions, but I don't see any of the other function options. How do I add the basic list of functions or how do I create a custom function so that I can make an IF statement?

Here is a picture of what I see from the function builder with only 4 functions.

[image]

Comment: Quick note, I had a friend pull this up on Windows and the functions were there for them. This may be an OSX issue.

Answer (score 0):

The four functions that have shown up are the only functions that output Lists and I suspect that the column you created is a List column.  If you create a Floating Point column, you'll see the rest of the functions.

-- scooter